# Python Simple Quiz Program - How to solve the question loop

Tags: python

learner in the Python (with version 2.7.5).

Currently I am working on a simple quiz script that allows the user to re-answer a question, and limit the number of chances the user can answer a question incorrectly.

So a total limit of 5 is set and a message (e.g. "END!") would be displayed to the user when the limit is reached. The limit is shared across all questions.

When I was testing the below-mentioned script, I found several problems.

1) Even the question 1 is wrongly answered for 5 times, question 2 would still be displayed, how could I prevent the next question from appearing if the limit was already reached?

2) I would like to ask where should I insert the code for the end message ("END!") if the limit was reached?

Thanks a lot!

```
def quiz():
score = 0
counter = 0
print "Please answer the following questions:"
print "Question 1 - ?"
print "a."
print "b."
print "c."
while counter <5:
    answer = raw_input("Make your choice:")
    if answer == "c":
        print("Correct!")
        score = score +1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        counter = counter +1
print "Question 2 - ?"
print "a."
print "b."
print "c."
while counter <5:
    answer2 = raw_input("Make your choice:")
    if answer2 == "a":
        print("Correct!")
        score = score +1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        counter = counter +1
    print
    print ("Your score is ") + str(score)
```

p.s. the code seems a bit off-placed with the copy and paste function. Sorry for causing the inconvenience

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Without correct indentation is not obvious where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You should really refactor this to make it a little less repetitious. So I'd put the question and answer logic into their own function and pass in the question text and correct answer. However, using your code as-is, every time you increment the counter, you need to check if it's > 5 and just use `while True` for the loop. So for each question:

```
correct = "a"
while True:
    answer = raw_input("Make your choice:")
    if answer == correct:
        print("Correct!")
        score = score +1
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        counter = counter +1
        if counter == 5:
            print "END!"
            return
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always printing the second question without checking if the limit of wrong answers has been reached. Before printing the second question you could do something like

```
if counter >= 5:
    print "END!"
    return
```

The `return` statement inside the conditional would terminate the `quiz` function if the limit has been reached. This needs to be done before printing any question.

Also, you could improve your code using a list of questions with answers and a simple for loop to iterate over all the questions and avoid repeating the same logic every time.